# QVariant with std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, qt

i have the following problem, i am using

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE( std::shared_ptr<int> );
qRegisterMetaType< std::shared_ptr<int> >();
QMetaType::registerComparators< std::shared_ptr<int> >();
```

to use `std::shared_ptr<int>` with e.g. QListModel. 
I need a behavior where

```
QVariant::fromValue( std::shared_ptr<int>( new int(5) ) ) == QVariant::fromValue( std::shared_ptr<int>( new int(5) ) )
```

is true. My code above return false here since `std::shared_ptr<int>::operator== ()` compares the raw pointers. is it possible to register comparators other than the standard operators in `QMetaType::registerComparators`?

Comment: You use `std::shared_ptr<int>` in your variant, but `std::shared_ptr<int *>` in your comparator (variant holds `int`-pointers, comparator compares `int *`-pointers). Is that correct?

Comment: no, should be shared_ptr<int> everywhere ...

Comment: Why are you using shared_ptr rather than QSharedPointer in a Qt software?

Comment: Because it comes from a thrid party lib...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try using `registerConverter()` to allow implicit conversion of the `shared_ptr<int>` to a regular int, and compare them that way.  Obviously then you would not do `registerComparator()`.  An alternative would be to wrap `shared_ptr<int>` in your own class and implement comparison the way you want.

Or check out [`Q_DECLARE_SMART_POINTER_METATYPE`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_SMART_POINTER_METATYPE).